# polling file descriptor

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

for the embedded MIPS-based platform I'm implementing a small program to poll GPIO, i.e. I'm using chip vendor's user level GPIO library with basic functionality (open /dev/gpio, read, write pin etc.). The design is straightforward:

```
int gpio_fd;
fd_set rfds;

gpio_fd = gpio_open(...);

while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(gpio_fd, &rfds);

    if (select(gpio_fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0) {
        if (FD_ISSET(gpio_fd, &rfds)) {
            /* read pins and similar */
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm facing a serious problem - this application when ran with '&' at the end, i.e. put it in background, consumes 99% CPU, this is obviously because of tight loop, but I observed the similar approach in many networking code and it worked fine.

Am I missing something, can it be a defect of the gpio library ?

Actually, just a single "while(1) ;  "  does the same effect. Can it be the "natural" behavior of the kernel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` call should block until the file descriptor is readable.

What may be happening is that the device driver does not support the `select` call, and so it exits immediately rather than blocking.

Another possibility is that the call to `gpio_open` does not actually give you a real Unix file descriptor.  If that were `open("/dev/gpio", O_RDWR)` or something like that I'd have a lot more faith in it.

Comment: I've just skimmed through the gpio device driver and have not found 'poll/select' implementations. I think your assumption is correct, thanks for the hint !

Comment: @Mark - There may not be a specific implementation, just some sort of way for the device driver to signal to the OS that it's readable.  If I knew more about Linux device drivers I could give more specific advice than that.  I do know though that there are file descriptor types that do not implement any way for poll/select to work on them.  For example file descriptors referring to actual on-disk files.

Comment: I have just thought that 'select' could be intentionally non implemented in the GPIO library, IMHO gpio file handle is always ready, unlike for example socket. What would you say ?

Comment: @Mark - Well, it makes sense to me.  I just hate coming to conclusions without actually knowing for certain.  One thing you could check is if the `/* read pins and similar */` code is ever executed.  If it isn't, then something interesting is going on for sure because select is returning without setting any bits.

Comment: I ended up with usleep() in the main loop, which did the job - the program now doesn't consume that much CPU. I guess I'd stick with it for awhile, as long as it works :-)